# Time as input, print timetable in Perl

Tags: perl, time

I want to make a script in perl that, given an input time (e.g. 07:55) prints a timetable with the given time -15 minutes, -25 min, +1h 30 min, etc.

```
  Input: 07:55 (or 0755, or separate hours and minutes)
  Expected output: Thing 1:  07:40
                   Thing 2:  07:30
                   Thing 3:  08:25
```

but I'm having troubles searching for possible functions or easy ways to do it (I only think of a sum of minutes + adding `if`'s in case value is greater than 59, etc). Any suggestion? thank you.

Comment: Have a look at: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Calc/lib/Date/Calc.pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) module.
For example:

```
use DateTime;

my $h = 7;
my $m = 55;

my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year   => 2014,
    month  => 11,
    day    => 24,
    hour   => $h, 
    minute => $m,
);  

printf "%02d:%02d\n", $dt->hour, $dt->minute; # prints "07:55"

$dt->subtract(minutes => 15);
printf "%02d:%02d\n", $dt->hour, $dt->minute; # prints "07:40"

# and so on...
```

Comment: Ah, great! I used DateTime simply to print current time and I didn't know that extra functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::Piece) if you do not want to install an external module.

Here's a one-liner to show you how it works:

```
perl -e 'use Time::Piece; $ z= Time::Piece->strptime( "11:30", "%H:%M");  print $z-120;'
```

will return

```
Thu Jan  1 11:28:00
```